# Get result from query return object from mysql in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

This code working

```
let result = await mysqlconnection.query("SELECT * from table");
```

`result` contains some info without actual result from MySQL, but have connection and config properties;
`result[0]` returns null, but I need data from MySQL, so when I tried using

```
mysqlconnection.query("SELECT * from table", function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
});
```

it prints what I need, but asynchronically. My question is how to combine synchronous execution and get results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysqlconnection.query( 'SELECT * FROM table' ).then( result => {
   // ... use the result ...
} )
```